# Make in Grails a view load specific JavaScript using the Asset-Pipeline Plugin

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

I render my views using a layout `main.gsp`.

In `main.gsp` I specify the manifest file that I use for JavaScript:

```
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
```

In my [asset-pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/) manifest file I have around 20 scripts. Some are used in some views, some not. But when the page is loaded all scripts are loaded.

I like very much the asset-pipeline. It keeps things clean and manageable.

But I wonder if I can make a configuration changes so only needed scripts for the view are loaded. Maybe based on page title or a `<meta>` tag?

Comment: You could create multiple manifests, but the asset pipeline doesn't have any configuration options to say "only these on this page, and only those on that page, etc."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in my comment the asset pipeline doesn't have anything in it's configuration to handle this, but you can easily accomplish this if your requirements are simple enough.

For example, if your requirements are that "Some controllers and their views will have specific manifests, while others will default to the main manifest." you could do something like this in your layout:

```
<g:set var="specificAssetExists" val="${false}" />
<g:set var="specificAsset" val="${params.controller}_${params?.action ?: 'index'}.js" />
<asset:assetPathExists src="js/${specificAsset}">
  <g:set var="specificAssetExists" val="${true}" />
</asset:assetPathExists>

<g:if test="${specificAssetExists}">
  <asset:javascript src="${specificAsset}"/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
  <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
</g:else>
```

The above assumes you will name your controller/action specific manifest files with `controllerName_actionName.js`. You can also adjust the above code to suit your needs if they are different.

Comment: Brilliant idea, Joshua. Thumbs up!!

Comment: the folder prefix is not required `<asset:assetPathExists src="js/${specificAsset}">` should be `<asset:assetPathExists src="${specificAsset}">`